# Add different languages to Ubuntu log in screen?

Tags: 14.04, login, login-screen

So I am after installing Ubuntu, and it is after booting up for the first time. Here is the problem, it only has my native (Lithuanian) keyboard input available. But my password has special characters like '£', which are not available on this layout.

What am I supposed to do? I cannot log in to the system to add the necessary layouts. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 by the way.